# Q: cesium load gltf model from storage

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, gltf

I am trying to put my `.gltf` model into a database.  I built a restful API to get it from the database. But when I put the URL into Cesium's framework, an error occurs. The error is shown below.

[image]

```
      Sandcastle.addToolbarButton('models', function () {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    var model = viewer.scene.primitives.add(Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
      id: 'house',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test',
      // url: gltf_data,
      modelMatrix: modelMatrix,
      scale: 0.1
    }))
  }, 'singleModel')
```

front end javascript code

```
class Test(flask_restful.Resource):
def get(self):
    client = MongoClient()

    db = client['test']
    fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
    for x in fs.find():
        data = x.read()
        break
    data = data.decode('utf-8')
    # file = fs.find_one()
    return jsonify(data)
```

server end python code

Comment: Can you share the code that loads this model into Cesium?  It looks like you may need to call `JSON.parse()` to turn the string into an object.

Comment: that's the server end & front end code above. @emackey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix out by myself, i forget to translate the string to json object, i added a `json.loads(data)` at server end's code. it runs. Thanks @emackey you give me an advise